# how to limit search box words in php

Tags: php, explode, strlen

php How to limit words in a search box? I want limit words within 30 words and do not broken the phrase.

I think it should combine `strlen` and `explode`, but how to? and how to notice the custom when he is typing words?

Thanks.

Comment: How to limit what where exactly, can you add more detail about what you want to do?

Comment: Maybe you can count spaces, but i'm not sure is it good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's javascript related not PHP.

You may want to use jQuery and attach an onChange event.

If you need the PHP script it's:

```
echo implode( ' ', array_slice(explode(' ',$search),0,30) ); //> Expensive
```

Comment: I was thinking the same, but it could be PHP related, if for example, he wants to check the number of words server-side before querying a database, in the same way you would always validate input on the server.

Comment: more better? :) than what? XD

Comment: @yes123, more porblem is when custom type one letter `a` repeart `30+` times with no space key, so should add `substr` to limit the all words length.

Answer (score 3):

You can check PHP's [str_word_count function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) . You can count words .

Comment: i doubt that function can be useful for cutting

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = preg_replace('/^((?:\s*\w+){0,30}).*$/s', '$1', $string);
```

Comment: @yes123 not very simple. Words can be separated by more than one space.

Comment: +1, This is a problem, but maybe can first preg_replace 2+ space into one. Thanks.

Comment: @fish Yes, you can: `$string = preg_replace('/[ ]+/', ' ', $string);`